# How do I exclude a filename that contains '_All_Data' when using the Data Transfer feature on BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, uri, google-cloud-data-transfer

I'm using Google Cloud Storage as a source and BigQuery as the destination for a Data Transfer feature that's available in BigQuery.So, on the data source details when creating a new data transfer I need to input the 'Cloud Storage URI', but I don't know how to exclude files with a certain text such as '_All_Data' on the file name.

I've tried to use the pattern `bucket/filepath1/2023/*/*/filename_2023*!_All_Data.csv` which was provided by ChatGPT, but it didn't work. I was expecting that I would be able to extract all the files in 2023 with the filename starting with 'filename_2023', and exclude all the files that contains '_All_Data'.

Basically, my expectations is that I would be able to extract files such as:

- `bucket/filepath1/2023/05/03/filename_20230503.csv`
- `bucket/filepath1/2023/05/02/filename_20230502.csv`
- `bucket/filepath1/2023/03/03/filename_20230303.csv`

And exclude files such as:

- `bucket/filepath1/2023/05/03/filename_20230503_All_Data.csv`
- `bucket/filepath1/2023/05/02/filename_20230502_All_Data.csv`
- `bucket/filepath1/2023/03/03/filename_20230303_All_Data.csv`

Answer (score 0):

give this a try. I checked this worked.
basically you will have to copy the required files to another bucket and then use data transfer service from this new bucket.

the `grep -v 'All'` will ensure the file names having `All` in it will be excluded and other files will be copied to target-gcs-bucket

```
gsutil ls gs://your-source-gcs-bucket/*.* | grep -v 'All' | gsutil cp -I gs://your-target-gcs-bucket/
```

Comment: I've tried it and it gives me the error 'Bucket names may only contain lowercase letters, numbers, dashes, underscores, and dots' when I input it into the Cloud Storage URI field.

Comment: You probably have not replaced your bucket name properly, can you check this

Comment: Were you supposed to submit a link? I've used this 'gsutil ls gs://stor-track/*.* | grep -v '_All_Data' | gsutil cp -I gs://stor-track/' when I did my test. Also, I've pasted the code into chatGPT and it mentioned that 'gsutil cp -I gs://stor-track/' copies the remaining files to the Google Cloud Storage bucket. What I wanted to do is to transfer the data into a table in BigQuery. Just a note, I'm using the 'Data Transfer' feature in BigQuery.

Comment: apologies, what i meant is you will have to copy it to another temporary bucket using the files above and then use data transfer service to copy to bigquery. I will edit my answer above. hope this helps

Comment: Why do you need a temporary bucket if you can just directly transfer it to a table in BigQuery? Wouldn't there be a way to fix this pattern that I've tried to use (bucket/filepath1/2023/*/*/filename_2023*!_All_Data.csv)